# How to read an individual column from Dynamo-Db without using Scan in Node-js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have 4.5 millions of records in my Dynamo Db.

I want to read the the id of each record as a batchwise.

i am expecting something like offset and limit like how we can read in Mongo Db.

Is there any way suggestions without scan method in Node-JS.

I have done enough research i can only find scan method which buffers the complete records from Dynamo Db and the it starts scanning the records, which is not effective in performance basis.

Please do give me suggestion.

Comment: Try this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

Comment: If you give the schema for your table, we can maybe figure out a Query instead of a Scan.

Comment: And since you want the entire table, `Scan` is a valid option. The only reason Scan is performance wise bad is that it scans the whole table which is something what we want here.

Comment: You can also use AWS DataPipeline to transfer the data to S3 or RedShift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things to know about DynamoDB is that it is a Key-Value Store with support for secondary indexes.

DynamoDB is a bad choice if the application often has to iterate over the entire data set without using indexes(primary or secondary), because the only way to do that is to use the `Scan` API.

DynamoDB Table Scan's are (a few things I can think off)

1. Expensive(I mean $$$)
2. Slow for big data sets
3. Might use up the provisioned throughput

If you know the primary key of all the items in DynamoDB (some external knowledge like primary is an auto incremented value, is referenced in another DB etc) then you can use `BatchGetItem` or `Query`.

So if it is a one off thing then `Scan` is your only option else you should look into refactoring your application to remove this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view, there's no problem doing scans because (according to the [Scan doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html)):

- > DynamoDB paginates the results from Scan operations
- > You can use the ProjectionExpression parameter so that Scan only returns some of the attributes, rather than all of them

The default size for pages is 1MB, but you can also specify the max number of items per page with the `Limit` parameter.

So it's just basic pagination, the same thing MongoDB does with `offset` and `limit`.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.Scan) is an example from the docs of how to perform Scan with the `node.js` SDK.

Now, if you want to get all the IDs as a batchwise, you could wrap the whole thing with a `Promise` and resolve when there's no `LastEvaluatedKey`.

Below a pseudo-code of what you could do :

```
const performScan = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    let params = {
        TableName:"YOUR_TABLE_NAME",
        ProjectionExpression: "id",
        Limit: 100 // only if you want something else that the default 1MB. 100 means 100 items
    };
    let items = [];

    var scanExecute = cb => {
        docClient.scan(params, (err,result) => {
            if(err) return reject(err);

            items = items.concat(result.Items);
            if(result.LastEvaluatedKey) {
                params.ExclusiveStartKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
                return scanExecute();
            } else {
                return err
                    ? reject(err)
                    : resolve(items);
            }
        });
    };
    scanExecute();
});

performScan().then(items => {
    // deal with it
});
```

Comment: AWS SDK supports Promises https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html